# Strange unknown POST request repeatly to Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-post

I have my app run in production mode recently and realize in production.log that there are so many POST '/' request to my app URL. From the production.log files, I see that those POST requests come every 2 minutes.
The error in the log file looks like this...

`F, [2019-09-10T19:45:13.948722 #28016] FATAL -- : [d0a8aada-89cf-495c-b7ae-c996ca3b7595]
[d0a8aada-89cf-495c-b7ae-c996ca3b7595] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/"):`

My Rails app run on Ubuntu 18 and using Nginx + Passenger.

I try find way to block suspicious IP by look into /var/log/ngix but I can't find the IP that associated to POST request. I think I miss something big.

Could you help suggest if where should I inspect to get the source of those requested POST ? Any suggestion is very appreciate, thank you.

Comment: [rack-attack](https://github.com/kickstarter/rack-attack) might be something to look at to prevent requests like this from even reaching the Rails layer. There are many other security based gems that you could use.

Comment: You can see Nginx logs for more info like IP address etc.

Comment: @MarkMerritt Thank you so much. It really helps.